# C#: MVC с контролами из фонового потока

Tags: c#, многопоточность, mvc

Есть контроллер, который работает в отдельном потоке, т.к. на него вешается сетевая часть. В момент когда приходит сообщение от сервера, он создает объект в модели и вызывает событие. На событие подписан Вид. При вызове события отрисовывается модель. Проблема в том, что событие вызывается из другого потока, и метод из Вида соответственно тоже. Чтобы отрисовка происходила в нужном потоке, приходится на прямую обращаться к Виду, и вызывать у него метод `Invoke()`.

В итоге получается, что контроллер полностью зависим от Вида. И практически в каждом методе контроллера встречается такой код:

```
view.Dispatcher.Invoke(() => { model.OnChange...(...); });
```

На сколько понял, Контроллер ни как не должен быть связан с Видом.

Вот собственно вопрос: "Как сделать правильно?". Может быть, я не правильно понимаю концепцию MVC?

На всякий случай добавлю, Вид собран на WPF.

Answer (score 1):

1) Впервые вижу, чтобы View переводили как "Вид". Обычно его переводят как "Представление"

2) Для WPF самый подходящий паттерн - MVVM. MVC - это больше для WinForms

Теперь по коду. Вам не обязательно прокидывать view куда бы то ни было для доступа к диспетчеру. Чтобы этого избежать, вы легко можете использовать прокси объекты, например

Создадим интерфейс

```
public interface IUIInteraction
{
    void Invoke(Action action);
}
```

Реализация

```
public class UIInteraction : IUIInteraction
{
    public void Invoke(Action action)
    {
        Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(action);
    }
}
```

Прокинем в контроллер

```
public class MyController
{
    IUIInteraction _ui;

    public MyController(IUIInteraction ui)
    {
        _ui = ui;
    }


    public void DoStuff()
    {
        _ui.Invoke(() => {/*......*/});
    }
}
```

Всё. Теперь контроллер имеет возможность выполнять код в UI потоке, но при этом он зависит от вашего интерфейса, а не от кода представления.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Уже нашел простое решение. Просто перенес view.Dispatcher.Invoke(() ...) с методов из контроллера в методы View. Почему-то сразу не подумал, что там их можно использовать.